# Android Null Pointer Exception Thread Issue

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hey guys I'm running this code in Android:

```
public ServiceServer(String serverName) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
    this.serverThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            serverThreadProc();
        }
    };
}

private void serverThreadProc() {
    while (!this.stopRequested) {
        Socket sessionSocket = null;
        try {
            sessionSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            InetAddress sourceAddress = sessionSocket.getInetAddress();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Accepted new incoming connection ... "
                    + sourceAddress.toString());
            if (clientMap.containsKey(sourceAddress)) {
                ClientProcessor legacyProcessor = clientMap
                        .get(sourceAddress);
                legacyProcessor.shutdown();
            }
            ClientProcessor processor = new ClientProcessor(sessionSocket);
            processor.start();
            clientMap.put(sourceAddress, processor);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public int start() {

    try {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        this.serverPort = this.serverSocket.getLocalPort();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Server " + serverName + " started at "
                + this.serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }

    this.serverThread.start();

    return this.serverPort;
}

public void stop() {
    try {
        stopRequested = true;
        if (null != this.serverSocket) {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The server " + this.serverName + " has been stopped.");
}
```

and I'm getting a null pointer exception error that has something to do with my thread?  For some reason it gets hung up on the serverThreadProc() method.  Here is the stack trace I'm getting from the issue:

```
01-10 02:10:13.361: I/ActivityThread(2216): Pub com.whooznear.android: com.whooznear.android.ProfileProvider
01-10 02:10:13.642: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 44K, 4% free 6336K/6595K, paused 95ms
01-10 02:10:13.662: I/dalvikvm-heap(2216): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.805MB for 588816-byte allocation
01-10 02:10:13.801: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 109ms
01-10 02:10:14.051: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 8ms+15ms
01-10 02:10:17.462: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 603K, 11% free 6666K/7431K, paused 81ms
01-10 02:10:17.622: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 7167K/7431K, paused 5ms+13ms
01-10 02:10:17.971: W/Profile(2216): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-10 02:10:31.801: I/ConnectActivity(2216): IP Address:0
01-10 02:10:31.812: I/ServiceServer(2216): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
01-10 02:10:31.812: I/ConnectActivity(2216): Started at -1
01-10 02:10:31.861: W/dalvikvm(2216): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x40014760)
01-10 02:10:31.861: E/AndroidRuntime(2216): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
01-10 02:10:31.861: E/AndroidRuntime(2216): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 02:10:31.861: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:61)
01-10 02:10:31.861: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.access$0(ServiceServer.java:57)
01-10 02:10:31.861: E/AndroidRuntime(2216):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer$1.run(ServiceServer.java:52)
01-10 02:10:32.301: D/dalvikvm(2216): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 7% free 7187K/7687K, paused 9ms+11ms
01-10 02:10:34.761: I/Process(2216): Sending signal. PID: 2216 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is on the line: sessionSocket = this.serverSocket.accept().   I know it's on that line I'm just unsure on how to get rid of the error

Comment: are you sure serverSocket is not null?

Comment: Yes I replaced the line: private ServerSocket serverSocket = null; with private ServerSocket serverSocket; and I still got the same issue.  So based on that I'm sure it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting NullPointerException at Line 61 in ServiceServer.java
One of the objects on which you are making a call seems to be Null

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>   com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:61)

plz check the line 61 in class ServiceServer

ps: this problem, i dont suggestion post here, all the log error information you can check and find the error place.

Comment: I added the code:
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
above the code:
    sessionSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
in the try/catch block and it worked!